# why paypal sdk return success but the transaction doesn't happen?

Tags: paypal, payment

I am implementing paypal payment using paypal sdk buttons , I click on the button opens the widget allows me to complete the purchase . if you check in the API CALL it has the status 201 ok , but the money does not reach the destination account:
follow my code

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&currency=EUR&disable-funding=card">
</script>
paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'pill',
        label: 'paypal'
    },
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                description: 'Products Purchase',
                items: items,
                 application_context: {
                cancel_url: '<?php echo $base_path.'/payment.php';?>' // Your cancel URL here
            },
                amount: {
                    currency_code: 'EUR',
                    value: totalAmount, // Total amount for all products
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: 'EUR',
                            value: totalAmount
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        console.log(data);
          console.log('aprovado o pagamento');

    },
    onError: function(err) {
    
        console.log('Payment error:');
        console.log(err);
        
       
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside `onApprove` must capture the transaction and look at the result to determine whether the capture was successful or not. Your code is not doing a capture, therefore there will be no transaction.

Also, `actions.order.create(` and `actions.order.capture(` are both deprecated and should not be used in any new integration. See the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) or [integration builder](https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/) for information and samples of creating and capturing with a backend (server-side code).